# Swift: Use of unresolved identifier 'FDataSnapShot' when using firebase SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm developing app with firebase with swift.
I got error when using FDataSnapShot.
Here is my code.

```
    DataService.dataService.DATA_REF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        var newItems = [FDataSnapshot]()

        // loop through the children and append them to the new array
        for item in snapshot.children {
            newItems.append(item as! FDataSnapshot)
        }

        // replace the old array
        self.items = newItems
    })
```

I installed firebase sdk with cocoapods.
My pod file looks like this.

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase'
target 'nos' do
end
```

Is there anybody who has experience in this?
*Note: I'm using the latest version of Xcode(7.2).
I really hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Try adding `import Firebase` in your class header. Also, do `ctrl+k` & `ctrl+b` to clean the cache and rebuild your project w/ your new Firebase CocoaPod

Comment: Sorry, it works fine.

Comment: I already imported Firebase in app delegate but it didn't work.

Comment: And for now, I implemented 'import Firebase' to view controller and it works fine.Thanks.

Comment: what version of cocoapods are you using - run `pod --version` to find out.

Comment: @AntonKolya If that got you squared away, I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're attempting to use on a `UIViewController`, make sure you add:

```
import Firebase
```

to `YourViewController`, clean cache (`ctrl+k`), and rebuild (`ctrl+b`) after you've added the CocoaPod to your project.